# Space Invaders ASCII, shoot stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii

I'm doing some work for a class, and I'm building space invaders game in ASCII.
I know that I can do better code, using objects, but in my case I can't use it! 
I also know that I have others errors on code, but I only want to know an answer!

When I shoot (pressing space), and then I shoot again and if the first shoot isn't collide with a alien, the first shoot just stops! and I really don't know why!

I have comments and vars in Portuguese, but if you don't understand something, just ask!

Code: http://pastie.org/private/fbnjo8vczkxq6quoem6tig

online: http://www.tomahock.com/Projecto-LabMM3/spaceInvaders.html

P.S. I know that isn't the best code ever! And it is an alpha version lots to do yet!

Comment: Try code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like a lot of effort . But i doubt the output worth !! its very slow. Why dont you use jquery animation and make a game which will be very user friendly and eye candy

Comment: @zod i haven't though it.. gonna try it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maintain a list of projectiles and update the entire list each game iteration. It looks like you are only updating the current projectile, and once you shoot one it ignores all previous ones even though they should be updated. That means each iteration you must check for collisions, update location, and check for off of screen for every projectile in the list.

Comment: my vars tirosT[] contains all timers tiggerd by setInterval, and tiros[] is the ids to tiros. and i check it for colisions in every move of the projectile!

Comment: you need to check for collisions in every move for ALL projectiles, not just the last one shot.